# Unable to validate Dto with ModelState.IsValid

Tags: c#, webapi, modelstate

I have a Dto class `ContactInformationDto` which contains the fields `Phonenumber` and `Emailaddress`. In my endpoint I want to use `ModelState.IsValid` to check whether both fields meet the requirements I have set.

The `ContactInformationDto` looks like this:

```
public class ContactInformationDto
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phonenumber is required")]
    [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Phonenumber is too long")]
    public string Phonenumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Emailaddress is required")]
    public string Emailaddress { get; set; }
}
```

My endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveContactInformation([FromBody] ContactInformationDto contactInformation, CancellationToken cancelllationToken)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

When I run the following unit test `ModelState.IsValid` is always `true` and the test fails.

```
public async Task SaveContactInformation_IfNoPhoneNumber_ThenBadRequest()
{
    var contactInformation = new ContactInformationDto
    {
        Emailaddress = "example@example.com"
    }

    var actionResult = await _controller.SaveContactInformation(contactInformation, _cancellationToken);
    
    Assert.IsBadRequest(actionResult);
}
```

My other test with a `Phonenumber` longer than the allowed number of characters alse fails.

---- Solution ----
@Xerillio points out correctly that modelstate validation does not happen in the unit test I'm using here.
I added an error in my unit test to the modelstate to test how my method reacts to `Model.IsValid` and an integration test to test if my validation attributes are correct.

Comment: In your `Required` attributes, try setting `AllowEmptyStrings` to false.

FYI, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations has [EmailAddress] and [Phone] attributes.

Comment: @BenOsborne That doesn't make a difference.

Comment: If you want to test that the ASP.NET framework applies model validation according to your validation attributes, you should look into [integration testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0). The model validation is not applied in the unit you want to test, so unit testing this logic is not possible.

Comment: @Xerillio You are right of course!